# Fire Emblem Fates: How can I transfer my units/items/weapons from one save file to another one?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

I have finished fire emblem fates conquest some times ago and I heard it was possible to move your units through the save files, but how? I have some great units such as xander, leo, laslow and niles with great weapons such as the killer bow, the leo's iceblade and some elixirs.
So how do I do move the units and items from one save file to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to beat the game. Once you beat it, you can transfer up to 5 characters that are *still alive at the time of beating the game* as units that you can purchase in the Einherjar store in other playthroughs.